Not Able to Get User Modified Data Using pdf-lib in Angular
I am working on an Angular application where I need to render an existing fillable PDF using pdf-lib. The PDF can have some pre-filled data, and users are allowed to edit this data or fill in new information. However, when I submit the PDF to generate a JSON representation of the data, only the existing (pre-filled) data is being converted into JSON, and the modifications made by the user are not included.
Here is the stackblitz link to reproduce the issue
"https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/jijoece/angular-pdf-editor"

Please copy and paste the stackblitz link to the browser, it gets modified somehow when clicking on it

I used the same URL, logged in from a different browser, and saw the option to create a fork. The repo is public, I am not sure if there is anything else that I have to do.

"I'm rendering the PDF in an iframe, and it uses Google Chrome's PDF plugin for rendering. I need to capture the changes that are manually made in the browser once the PDF is rendered, but I'm not sure how to extract that from the iframe. I attempted to save the iframe content locally upon clicking submit, but it doesn't include the changes. However, when I select the save button inside the rendered PDF at the top right, it provides an option to save the file with or without the changes. I need to mimic the 'save file with changes' functionality.
